# In Pandas, count rows that match multiple criteria based on values within the same DataFrame, and add the count in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with an index, and then a reference to other indexes, and an organization. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'index' :1, 'refIndex':3, 'org' : 'org1'}, {'index':2, 'refIndex':1, 'org': 'org1'}, {'index':3, 'refIndex': 2, 'org' : 'org2'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print df
```

Output:

```
   index   refIndex   org
0  1       3          org1
1  2       1          org1
2  3       2          org2
```

What I need to do is count on each row how many other rows where that row's index occurs as the refIndex from the same org.

So I end up with a DataFrame like:

```
   index   refIndex   org    count
0  1       3          org1   1        # index 1 org1 occurs as refIndex and org once elsewhere
1  2       1          org1   0        # index 2 org1 occurs as refIndex and org nowhere else
2  3       2          org2   0        # index 3 org2 occurs as refIndex and org nowhere else
```

I am new to Python and Pandas, so please excuse if this is obvious to you. I have been struggling all day with trying groupbys, functions, for loops inside for loops, merges.

Comment: What do you mean by *"index 1 org1 occurs as refIndex and org once elsewhere"*?

Comment: @Vishnudev - In the 2nd row, the refIndex is 1 (matching the first row's index 1 value) and org is "org 1" (also matching the first row's org value).

Comment: Then shouldn't it be marked as 1 ? @DrWhat

Comment: count is marked as 1 for index 1, because this index occurs as refIndex with same org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Numpy broadcasting

```
i, r, o = df.values.T
df['count'] = np.sum((i[:, None] == r) & (o[:, None] == o), axis=1)
```

#### Explanations

Create a boolean mask by comparing every value in `index` column with every value in `refIndex` column.

```
>>> (i[:, None] == r)

array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

Create another boolean mask by comparing every value in `org` column with every other value in the `org` column itself.

```
>>> (o[:, None] == o)

array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True]])
```

Take the **`logical and`** of the above two boolean masks so that we could be able to mask the `True` values in first boolean mask which does not belong to the same organisation.

```
>>> (i[:, None] == r) & (o[:, None] == o)

array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

Finally take `sum` along `axis=1` to count of rows where the row's `index` occurs as the `refIndex` from the same `org`.

```
>>> df

   index  refIndex   org  count
0      1         3  org1      1
1      2         1  org1      0
2      3         2  org2      0
```

Comment: Because my real DataFrame is more complex, I created arrays from my DataFrame - same as your i, r, o arrays, added additional conditions (some with fixed values), and it just worked perfectly. Thank you very much for this remarkably straightforward solution, and the exceptionally clear explanation of the underlying principle. I once was lost, but now am found.

Comment: Is there a way to evaluate dates using this method? for example, if I have a new column "StartDate", of datetime64[ns], and need to count only those with StartDate > '2021-01.31', I get typeError '>' not supported between 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'.

Comment: @DrWhat Lets discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)

Comment: After experiencing some issues when creating the masks with multiple arrays, I ultimately found it more reliable to create individual masks for each array comparison (like the answer, just no & or | chaining when creating the masks). For other criteria, checking values in the dataframe for a condition, normal boolean arrays were created. And then finally, all these boolean arrays could be checked against each other using the necessary logic described in the numpy broadcasting np.sum approach of this answer. When all conditions were true, it summed, much like a sumproduct in excel.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'id'})
groups = df.groupby('org')
df.apply(lambda x: x.refIndex not in groups.get_group(x.org)['id'], axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: When I try to put this into my real dataset, I keep getting a KeyError: nan.  My Keys are correct... not sure why that might happen.

Comment: You have a column named `index`. It is a bad practice to use inbuild keywords as names.

Comment: Indeed! Others beware of my foolishness. In the answer, the word index should be changed to whatever your index is actually called. Bravo Vishnudev.

Comment: If I change my code to the "index" as "Id", and 'org).index' to 'org).Id', I still get the raise KeyError(name) KeyError: nan

Comment: Rename only the index column. I have edited the answer @DrWhat

Comment: If i run only the code we have both provided, your solution works perfectly. I can add a column for the df.apply output. It is probably my fault why I can't get rid of the KeyError. Sorry.

Comment: If I add a fourth row, with Index 4, refIndex 2, org org1, then the output no longer counts the first row as 1, it is now 0; and counts the new row as 1.